# Count number of times the place is visited in a particular month in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to count the number of time a place is visited in particular month and maintain the count in the column with heading of same month in another csv file in python language.I am attaching my csv file which consist of check-in records.

[image: csv screenshot]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("f:/locpop.csv") 

counted = df.groupby(["placeid"]).size() 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date) 
Month_cnt = df.groupby(["placeid"]).size().filter(df["date"].m‌​onth==01)

a = pd.DataFrame(counted)
b = pd.DataFrame(Month_cnt)
a.to_csv("f:/Location_Count.csv",header=['Count']) 
b.to_csv("f:/Location_Count.csv",header=['January'])
```

Comment: I was trying by using Groupby function and filter but it didn't work for me@lordingtar

Comment: Upload your code, we will try to fix it for you

Comment: Couldn't get your comment @Mayeul sgc

Comment: `df=df.loc[(df['placeid']==placeId) & (df['date'].month==01)]` sorry had some mistakes. Basically this code will create a new dataframe with all the line of new for a given date, then you just check the size of the df to have your number

Comment: sorry I am not understanding what you are trying to tell...@Mayeulsgc